# SQL Server : how to replace or convert string "ddMMM" to date "MMMdd"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, where-clause

How to replace or convert in [SQL Server]?

I have tables as shown here:

```
startDate
varchar(5)
----------
08MAY
01JUN
02JUN
10JUN


station
varchar(4)
----------
ICN
LAX
SFO
ICN
```

`startDate` column are of type `varchar` but store data like 'ddMMM'

I request 01JUN ~ 10JUN in SQL query like this...

```
select * 
from dbo.temp 
where convert(varchar(5), Startdate) >= convert(varchar(4), '01JUN')
```

... but, the wrong query.

Please advice me

Comment: You want to convert your startDate field to a standard date or you want to keep the format as is but filter on that field to get data from 01Jun to 10Jun ?

Comment: I'm kinda surprised nobody linked to Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Answer (score 2):

You should really fix your data model, and store dates as a date-like datatype rather than strings. Storing dates as string, especially in this akward format, makes very simple things much more complicated that they need to.

For just these 10 days of June, string comparison is enough:

```
where startdate between '01JUN' and '10JUN'
```

A more general solution involves converting the string to a real date. Assuming you want dates in 2020, then:

```
where datefromparts(
    '2020'
    case right(startdate, 3)
        when 'JAN' then  1
        when 'FEB' then  2
        when 'MAR' then  3
        when 'APR' then  4
        when 'MAY' then  5
        when 'JUN' then  6
        when 'JUL' then  7
        when 'AUG' then  8
        when 'SEP' then  9
        when 'OCT' then 10
        when 'NOV' then 11
        when 'DEC' then 12
    end,
    left(startdate, 2)
) between '2020-06-01' and '20200610'
```

If you wanted to fix your schema (which, again, is what you should focus on), you could use the same conversion technique:

```
-- create a new column
alter table mytable add startdate2 date;

-- set it
update mytable 
set startdate2 = datefromparts(
    '2020'
    case right(startdate, 3)
        when 'JAN' then  1
        when 'FEB' then  2
        when 'MAR' then  3
        when 'APR' then  4
        when 'MAY' then  5
        when 'JUN' then  6
        when 'JUL' then  7
        when 'AUG' then  8
        when 'SEP' then  9
        when 'OCT' then 10
        when 'NOV' then 11
        when 'DEC' then 12
    end,
    left(startdate, 2)
);

-- drop the old column
alter table mytable drop column startdate;

-- rename the new column
exec sp_rename 'mytable.startdate2' , 'startdate', 'COLUMN';
```

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% clear if you are looking for a DATE or String.  The following has both options

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([startDate] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('08MAY')
,('01JUN')
,('02JUN')
,('10JUN')

Select *
      ,AsADate   = try_convert(date,stuff(startDate,3,0,' ')+' 2020')
      ,AsAString = right(StartDate,3)+left(StartDate,2)
 from @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
startDate   AsADate     AsAString
08MAY       2020-05-08  MAY08
01JUN       2020-06-01  JUN01
02JUN       2020-06-02  JUN02
10JUN       2020-06-10  JUN10
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that yo are storing dates as a `varchar` is a problem unto itself, and that version you are storing is **language specific**. Ideally, you should never be storing dates as a `varchar`; they do not behave the same. For example `'02DEC'` is **before** `31JAN'` or `'MAR17'` is **after** `'APR01'`.

To achieve this, you're going to need to convert to a `date` and then back to a `varchar`. This will only work in a language based language; if a `LOGIN` is using French, German, Japanese, this is not going to work (to make it work, you need to fix your data model).

```
SELECT V.YourColumn,
       UPPER(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(6),CONVERT(date,STUFF(V.YourColumn,3,0,' ') + ' 2000',100),107),' ','')) AS NewColumn
FROM (VALUES('08MAY'),
            ('01JUN'),
            ('02JUN'),
            ('10JUN'))V(YourColumn)
```

This has several parts to it. Firstly `STUFF` inject a space between the days and month part of your `varchar`; giving `'01 JUN'` for example. Then we concatenate `' 2000'` to the value to create a value date (2000 as it's a leap year, just in case you have a `'29FEB'`).

Then, once we have a valid format date, for example `'01 JUN 2000'` we `CONVERT` it to a `date` using the style 100 (`mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)`). Using a style code just ensure the `CONVERT` should work regardless of the **English** based language.

After that we `CONVERT` the `date` back to a `varchar` using style code 107 (`Mon dd, yyyy`). As the `varchar` is defined as a `varchar(6)`, then the value is truncated to `Mon dd`.

Finally, we remove the space between `Mon` and `dd` and the apply `UPPER` to make the letters upper case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your startDate column to a standard date otherwise you will run into problems one of which is how will you filter your data outside of the few days and what happens if you have 2 years of data in your table then how are you going to decide which year is your filter for.( 1 Jun 2020 or 1 Jun 2021)

```
Select startDate,CONVERT(DATE,CONCAT(startDate,'2020')) as standard_startDate from tbl_date

startDate   standard_startDate
01JUN        2020-06-01
02JUN        2020-06-02
08MAY        2020-05-08

ALTER TABLE tbl_date
ALTER COLUMN startDate varchar(10)

UPDATE tbl_date
SET startDate = CONVERT(DATE,CONCAT(startDate,'2020'))

ALTER TABLE tbl_date
ALTER COLUMN startDate DATE
```